# How to copy all my tables from a Postgres db to another one without pg_dump?

Tags: postgresql

I need to copy all my tables from my Postgres database to another one. Usually I'd do it with pg_dump and then pg_restore, but unfortunately I don't have rds_superuser permissions and so it doesn't work.

Basically I have to copy the data table by table, create table in the other db and then import the data. This is how I would do if I'd have to do it manually.

Does anybody know how to do this in a programmatic way?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use foreign tables. Or check if the SQL tool you are using allows to export the data e.g. in CSV format

Answer (score 1):

If you have createdb privilege, you can try using something like below.

`CREATE DATABASE newdb WITH TEMPLATE originaldb OWNER your_user_name;`

It will copy all your tables(with structure) and data to your new db from your old one.